# How to implement NSArray method in IBAction?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, rgb

I have been reading the code that was suggested to me in this thread here: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

I am wondering how I would implement the code in the following manner:

```
-(IBAction)getRGB:(id)sender {
    // Call getRGBAsFromImage here when pressed. 
}

+ (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count {
   ...
}
```

Thank you very much.

Edit for 0x90:

```
-(IBAction)getRGB:(id)sender {    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0121.JPG"];
    [self getRGBAsFromImage:image atX:40 andY:40 count:40];
}
```

Comment: um, add `+ (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count;` to your header file and call `[self getRGBAsFromImage:image atX:xx andY:yy count:count];` from getRGB??

Comment: This also fixed the previous error. Now I can't seem to properly load the image variable

Answer (score 1):

You would define a strong/retained (depends on whether you use ARC) property to store the returned `NSArray` and then call the method as such:

```
-(IBAction)getRGB:(id)sender {
    propertyYouDefined = [self getRGBAsFromImage:image atX:42 andY:42 count:42];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That resolved the error with not being able to call the function. Do you have any advice on how to load the 'image' aspect? I have a JPG in my resources folder I would like to use.

Comment: In my IBAction I am attempting this: NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0121" ofType:@"JPG"];
    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: While there are many ways to load images, the easiest way to load an image is: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0121.JPG"];

Comment: Hmm I tried that (please view edited post). Should it be placed in the IBActon or the NSArray?